# How to make a list item show/hide a DIV list or specified items of the DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 lists:

· A "source" selector;
· A "content" of the selected source;

I need to know how to turn each item of the source list into a button, to show only it's content when clicked, and stay highlighted when selected, just like the iTunes Smart Playlists (for example).

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you done so far?

Comment: jQuery is your LIFESAVER

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (seems jQuery does not work here correctly. please give it a try on ur system)

**here you may see a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfw2123u/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#tabs li").click(function(e){
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            var tabNum = $(this).index();
            var nthChild = tabNum+1;
            $("ul#tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $("ul#tab li.active").removeClass("active");
            $("ul#tab li:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
ul#tabs {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
ul#tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #32c896;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul#tabs li:hover {
  background-color: #238b68;
}
ul#tabs li.active {
  background-color: #238b68;
}
ul#tab {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul#tab li {
  display: none;
}
ul#tab li.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tabs">
  <li class="active">Tab 1</li>
  <li>Tab 2</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="tab">
  <li class="active">
    <h2>This is the first tab</h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>This is the second tab</h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Tab number three wee hee</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```